# Scaling Imaging from URL using Web Broswer Control

Tags: vba, ms-access, webbrowser-control

I am having a problem trying to get a Web Browser control in a MS Access form to display an image from a URL correctly.

I am using .navigate (strImagePath) to place the imaging in to WebBrowser1. That works fine. The images are jpg and I have the full path and image filename.

The problem is the that the image is displayed at 100% scale, which is larger than the size of the browser. I can use zoom (OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM) to scale the image, but this only works if I know the size of the image, which I don't to get the right zoom factor.

Ideally, I would like to have the image fit to window without having to determine the image size.

It that is not possible, the other option is to determine the image size and then set the appropriate zoom. I have not figured a way to determine the image size without saving it locally. Which would be a big overhead and add a unacceptable lag to the form display, specially when move through records. Any ideals here?

Thanks

Comment: If you simply are pulling pictures from the web, you may be better off with the method described here: [Display pictures directly from an URL](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl).

Comment: Gustav, thanks for the suggestion. As I mentioned, I was trying to avoid downloading to a local file. Reading the instructions for your API, the files are downloaded to a local cache, which then allows for the files to be loaded as a local file. I am looking for a direct approach.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it running after the code from Thomas.

There is the final code.

```
Public Function DisplayImage(ctlImageControl As Control, strImagePath As Variant) As String
On Error GoTo Err_DisplayImage

Dim strResult As String
Dim intHeight As Integer
Dim intWidth As Integer
Dim intHeightZoom As Integer
Dim intWidthZoom As Integer
Dim intPageZoom As Integer

With ctlImageControl
    If strImagePath = "" Then
        .Visible = False
        strResult = "No image name specified."
    Else
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate (strImagePath)
    
        Do While .Object.Busy Or .Object.ReadyState <> 4 'wait to imaged loaded
            DoEvents
        Loop
        intHeight = .Document.images(0).clientHeight
        intWidth = .Document.images(0).clientWidth
        intHeightZoom = CLng(21600) / intHeight
        intWidthZoom = CLng(43200) / intWidth
        If intHeightZoom < intWidthZoom Then
            intPageZoom = intHeightZoom
        Else
            intPageZoom = intWidthZoom
        End If
        .Object.ExecWB OLECMDID_OPTICAL_ZOOM, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, _
        CLng(intPageZoom), vbNull

        strResult = "success"
   End If
End With

Exit_DisplayImage:
    DisplayImage = strResult
    Exit Function

Err_DisplayImage:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 2220       ' Can't find the picture.
            ctlImageControl.Visible = False
            strResult = "Can't find image in the specified name."
            Resume Exit_DisplayImage:
        Case Else       ' Some other error.
            MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
            strResult = "An error occurred displaying image."
            Resume Exit_DisplayImage:
    End Select
End Function
```

There the function is called by

```
    Me!txtFaceResults = DisplayImage(Me!WebBrowser1, strFullImageName)
```

While it works to zoom the images to a uniform size, the scaling is still off. But the general process works of loading the images in to the ActiveX Web Browser object. Reads the image size and calculates a zoom factor and then apply the zoom. It is important to wait for the image to load, otherwise you will either get an error or the size of the previously loaded image.

I was not able to use HtmlImg Type as Thomas used, so I got the elements individually. I used the documentation on Mozilla at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element
to see the element available.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only the image loaded, the following code will get you the width and height of that image.

```
Dim img As HtmlImg
Set img = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.images(0)
Debug.Print img.naturalHeight, img.naturalWidth
```

However, I was not really able to calculate the correct zoom factor nor to pass a variable zoom factor to the `ExecWB`-method - I always got a runtime error, not matter which data type I used (constant values are working).

Plus, at least in my tests, the image was displayed with (white) borders which also would influence the zoom factor. Anyhow, the width and height are exactly the dimensions of the test image I was playing with.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I tried to use what you wrote, but for me HtmlImg is not a define type. But I think you are on to something. Any suggestions on HtmlImg?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that you need to add a reference to the *Microsoft HTML Object LIbrary*. Or you declare the variable as Object (but then you don't have intellisence support)